# Search for text within square brackets and speech marks SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am wanting to search for text within brackets and speech marks. The values in the column look like this: `["flour","butter","eggs"]`

I have tried:

```
SELECT * FROM 'posts' WHERE ingredients = '''butter'''
```

Th, however,er does not work.

How can I write a query to return the rows only containing the desired words? All help is much appreciated.

Ps. I know the data should not have been stored like this and it is not in the correct normal form. I just need a way to search for this for now.

Comment: You should store ingredients in a separate table to keep your data normalized. Otherwise you are going to pay heavy price for keeping ingredients in a single column, because you would need to implement things that DB gives you for free (e.g. searching, adding, and deleting the individual items).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if this is JSON, you should store it as JSON, not a string.

That said, you can use `LIKE`:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM posts p
WHERE ingredients LIKE '%"butter"%';
```

Some comments about quotes.  You seem very confused by quotes in your query.

- You have `'posts'` as a table name in single quotes.  This will actually return an error.  The only quoting allowed here are escape characters (backticks).  However, they are not needed.
- Your data has double quotes around the values.  However, you have doubled up single quotes in your comparison string.  Single quotes and double quotes are different things.